# UILocalNotification not firing when device is locked

Tags: ios, ios4, ios6, uilocalnotification

My app I'm developing is a alarm type app. When the user presses the home button, I schedule a few UILocalNotifications to fire at certain intervals. The notifications fire at the right time when I press the home button and exit the app, but they don't fire at all if I press the Lock button. I've searched around but haven't found out why this is yet.

As I said, it works fine when I press the home button first. They fire at the right times, but if I press the "Lock" button at the top of the phone they don't fire after that. Anybody have any ideas as to why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked whether the app is allowed to display notifications in the lock screen? Check in settings.

Comment: Just checked on my phone, it's allowed, but still won't fire when locked. Just tried on the simulator too but it doesn't have any notification settings and still doesn't fire on there either.

Comment: What OS version and devices are you testing it with?

Comment: I'm using iOS 6 in the simulator, and iOS 6 on an iPhone 5 and 3rd generation iPad.

Comment: check the device logs - does it say anything that indicates the issue? (and how can one lock the simulator?

Comment: @Daij-Djan - Simulator -> Hardware -> Lock or just cmd+L

Answer (score 0):

This is because the lock button does not exit your application.

I assume you are setting up the `UILocalNotifications` in `applicationWillTerminate:` in your application delegate. If you add some logging in this method, you will see that it isn't called when using the lock button.

Setting up your notifications in `applicationWillResignActive:` might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but might help someone. This issue has been so overlooked on SO and no tutorial over the internet. Anyway, what you need to do is set `UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground` when setting `UIUserNotificationSettings`, and you should be good to go.

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP specifically set IOS6

Comment: That's why i said it might help someone in future, and it is obvious since i am answering the question after 3 years, it is not intended for OP.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks :)